# Use XML Annotations to find True Positives, False Positive and False Negative

Tags: python, xml, opencv, annotations, bounding-box

I am working on person detection and I have results in the form of bounding boxes that represent the detected person.

Now I need to calculate Precision and Recall for the results.

I am aware that I need to calculate True Positives, False Positives and False Negatives in order to get P & R.

I have manually annotated the data using an annotation tool called Vatic.
In the end Vatic generated an XML file that consists of the coordinates of the bounding boxes of the ground truth.

The content of the XML file are (I didn't bother to close the tags but included them to give an idea of the content):

```
<object>
<name>People</name>
<moving>true</moving>
<action/>
<verified>0</verified>
<id>1</id>
<createdFrame>0</createdFrame>
<startFrame>0</startFrame>
<endFrame>1</endFrame>
      <polygon><t>0</t><pt><x>434</x><y>422</y><l>1</l></pt><pt><x>434</x><y>574</y><l>1</l></pt><pt><x>582</x><y>574</y><l>1</l></pt><pt><x>582</x><y>422</y><l>1</l></pt></polygon>
      <polygon><t>1</t><pt><x>432</x><y>421</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>432</x><y>573</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>580</x><y>573</y><l>0</l></pt><pt><x>580</x><y>421</y><l>0</l></pt></polygon>
```

For this question I have used an annotation for 2 frames only, else the code would have been huge.

I interpret the XML as, <t> states the frame number, <x> and <y> are the coordinates of the 4 corners of the bounding box. Don't really understand what <l> tag specifies.

How can I use this XML and compare it with the results that I have, to calculate True Positives, False Positive and False Negative?

The results are in form of images with bounding boxes created by the HOG detector.

Can this be done using some sort of a open source tool? Or would it be easier to write code to compute these things? Can it be done with OpenCV and Python (preferred)?

Thanks